# When there is setupController the model value returned from the model hook is null

Tags: ember.js

Why when adding `setupController` to a route the `model` value returned from the `model` hook is `null` ?

http://jsbin.com/pahuno/1/edit

I know i could work around it by setting up the `model` value in the `setupController` but I want to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hovonahiwugi/1/edit)

When you use a hook, such as `setupController` or `renderTemplate`, you are preventing Ember from handling the default case. Make a call to the default method:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

From a comment in the Ember source:

> This method is called with the controller for the current route and
>   the
>       model supplied by the `model` hook.
>
> By default, the `setupController` hook sets the `model` property of
>       the controller to the `model`.   If you implement the `setupController` hook in your Route, it will
>       prevent this default behavior. If you want to preserve that behavior
>       when implementing your `setupController` function, make sure to call
>       `_super`: